# How do I bind the LostFocus and GotFocus events to view model commands?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am a new in C# and MVVM approach, I created such `TextBox`

```
<TextBox x:Name="Tb_fps"
         Grid.Column="0"
         Text="{Binding FPS, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         x:FieldModifier="private" 
         Margin="4,4,0,4" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

and as you can see I am using `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, but additionally I would like to use `LostFocus` and `GotFocus` events...

But I can't with this implementation of DataBinding...

Question is - how to handle all this events on one `TextBox` view?

**EDIT**

Associated with @Joe H answer

[image]

Comment: `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` would update the source property on every change of the target property. Why would you need more than that? The target property (i.e the TextBox's Text) won't change when the focus changes.

Comment: If you update the binding on PropertyChanged, by the time LostFocus fires you would never have anything to update there. Additionally, there is no GotFocus event for bindings.

Comment: Yes there are reasons one might want to handle these events I have applications that need to do something with the text when a user moves to the next control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an EventTrigger from the

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

namespace.

This allows the conversion of an event into a ICommand pattern.  Also you don't need the EventSource as that is the default for triggering a binding.  This would be the Xaml and the ViewModel code follows

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" Height="40" Width="80">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LostFocusCommand}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GotFocusCommand}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="Need something to change focus to" Height="40" Width="80" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _text;

    public string Text
    {
        get => _text;
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand LostFocusCommand => new ActionCommand(ExecuteLostFocus);

    private void ExecuteLostFocus()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("LostFocus");
    }

    public ICommand GotFocusCommand => new ActionCommand(ExecuteGotFocus);

    private void ExecuteGotFocus()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GotFocus");
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Also, you should be aware that the Text property in the ViewModel does not update until the TextBox loses focus.  If you want to capture text as it changes a TextChanged handler is needed

Comment: Could you please explain from where I get this event `OnPropertyChanged`? I see `LostFocusCommand ` event and `GotFocusCommand ` this one, but from where I get this `OnPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Edited my quesion ... Could not find value

Comment: You may need to add the Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf NuGet package if your using .NetCore that is required as they have stripped this out of the default framework

Comment: What about the first question?

Comment: OnPropertyChanged is just a method to fire the PropertyChangedEventHandler.  In order to send an update from the ViewModel to the View one needs to have the ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged and fire the PropertyChanged event.  One thing you may want to look at if new to WPF is one of the supporting open source frameworks.  A lot of people like MVVMLight because it is quite simple.  I prefer Prism but that is more complex

Answer (score 3):

You can bind to any event from XAML using the [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf) package.
After installing the package, you must include the behaviors namespace (`xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors`) to your XAML file. Then, you can use the `<i:InteractionTrigger>` markup in your control (which is a XAML `behaviour`).

This markup allows you to declare an `EventTrigger`, which works a bit like style triggers, if your familiar with this. You can specify the control event you want to hook up to, and then declare a `TriggerAction` markup to react to the event.
You will most likely want to use a `TriggerAction` of type `InvokeCommandAction`, that will bind to a command in your viewmodel.

Your code would look like this:

```xml
<TextBox
    x:Name="Tb_fps"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Margin="4,4,0,4"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    x:FieldModifier="private"
    Text="{Binding FPS, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LostFocusCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GotFocusCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

Edit: I changed System.Windows.Interactivity package to the Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf, which is a more recent and maintained package.

Comment: Is it the same answer as Joe H gave?

Comment: Pretty much yes, it wasn't here when I started writing it.

Comment: According to the timestamp his answer was here 15 minutes before yours... But actually doesn't matter

Comment: Then it tooks me 15 minutes to write and verify the answer :)